# Javascript not looping through the HTML table?

Tags: javascript

So I have a HTML code where I want to perform some basic subtraction calculation between 'High' and 'Low' columns in HTML. I have looped through the html table to fill it and thus I have tried to use Javascript code in the loop so that it can automatically calculate the difference too. But I am not getting the desired results. When I am printing the results through console.log, I am getting the same high and low for every iteration. I am not sure why since html table is in loop and table is made correctly

```
<table id='example' class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Open</th>
            <th>High</th>
            <th>Low</th>
            <th>Close</th>
            <th>Volume</th>
            <th>Buyers</th>
            <th>Sellers</th>
            <th>Ratio</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="people">
        {% for x,y in info.items %}
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">{{x|split}}</td>
            <td id= 'open'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'open'}}</td>
            <td id='high'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'high'}}</td>
            <td id='low'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'low'}}</td>
            <td>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'close'}}</td>
            <td>{{y|access_dictionary:'volume'}}</td>
            <td id='buyquantity'>{{y|access_dictionary:'buy_quantity'}}</td>
            <td id='sellquantity'>{{y|access_dictionary:'sell_quantity'}}</td>
            <td id='ratio'></td>
            <script>
                console.log(document.getElementById('high').innerHTML)
                console.log(document.getElementById('low').innerHTML)
                console.log(document.getElementById('open').innerHTML)
                
                d = document.getElementById('high').innerHTML - document.getElementById('low').innerHTML
                console.log(d)
                document.getElementById('ratio').innerHTML = d;
            </script>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: IDs ***MUST*** be unique in a given document.

Comment: where's the `{% for x,y in info.items %}` comes from?

Comment: IDS are unique.

Comment: info.items comes from views.py

Comment: IDs are not unique. they are the same for every iteration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sir, You Must have unique id for selecting element in Javascript.
Sir, Try this Code Below I Change code little bit. I do not have tested below code:

```
<table id='example' class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Open</th>
            <th>High</th>
            <th>Low</th>
            <th>Close</th>
            <th>Volume</th>
            <th>Buyers</th>
            <th>Sellers</th>
            <th>Ratio</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="people">
        {% for x,y in info.items %}
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">{{x|split}}</td>
            <td id='open{{x}}'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'open'}}</td>
            <td id='high{{x}}'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'high'}}</td>
            <td id='low{{x}}'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'low'}}</td>
            <td>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'close'}}</td>
            <td>{{y|access_dictionary:'volume'}}</td>
            <td id='buyquantity'>{{y|access_dictionary:'buy_quantity'}}</td>
            <td id='sellquantity'>{{y|access_dictionary:'sell_quantity'}}</td>
            <td id='ratio'></td>
            <script>
                console.log(document.getElementById('high{{x}}').innerHTML);
                console.log(document.getElementById('low{{x}}').innerHTML);
                console.log(document.getElementById('open{{x}}').innerHTML);
                
                d = Number(document.getElementById('high{{x}}').innerHTML) - Number(document.getElementById('low{{x}}').innerHTML)
                console.log(d);
                document.getElementById('ratio{{x}}').innerHTML = d;
            </script>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What did you changed ? Can you [edit] your answer to explain why and how this should fix the question ?

Comment: Thank you so much Abdul. Changing the id for every iteration worked